# android:background="?buttonSelectableBackground" , what "?" means?

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface

layout of android in xml.

what "android:background="?buttonSelectableBackground"" means?

I konw "android:background="@drawable/buttonSelectableBackground"" means,but i don't know that

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/titlebar_icon_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="?buttonSelectableBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/titlebar_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/titlebar_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titlebar_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_icon_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a reference to a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (`@`), use a question-mark (`?`), and the resource type portion is optional. For instance:

```
?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>
```

See the details at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html.

Comment: I did not know that: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: Specifically, it's a theme attribute. Think of it as dereferencing a pointer.